# Is there any equivalet to ASP.NET ViewState in other web technologies?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I want to know if there are other web development technologies which have something like `ViewState` of `ASP.NET`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a direct corollary in other environments/frameworks, but the concept itself is [simple enough to implement](http://www.alternateinterior.com/2006/09/a-viewstate-for-php.html) in any web environment.  It's nothing more than data that's been base64 encoded and placed in a `hidden` form field.

Comment: Thanks. I asked for statistics reasons and then decide on best design approach of my project.